# C# Delete a Directory/File and set ReadOnly Attribute

Tags: c#, exception, attributes, directory, delete-file

I have following problem, I want to delete a file/directory, but the problem is following: I'm setting the `FileAttribute.ReadOnly` to false with this code

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo("FileToDelete");
di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

Then I'm doing this

```
File.Delete("FileToDelete")
```

Then it throws this Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException'
>       occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The access to the path
>       "FileToDelete" has been denied.  //Changed the Path to FileToDelete

Comment: Are you deleteing file or directory? You are mixing it, you either should get Fileinfo, not DirectoryInfo or delete with Directory.Delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is you have an expression
`di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;`
that is not assigned, used etc. nowhere in the code.
Also you are mixing DirectoryInfo and FileAttributes. This is just wrong. What you really want (from the description) is to set file not to be read only and then delete it.
So, you have to it like this

```
File.SetAttributes("FileToDelete", File.GetAttributes("FileToDelete") & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
File.Delete("FileToDelete");
```

also please note that the exception you're getting can still occur if you will not have sufficient permissions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

as for the directories

```
new DirectoryInfo("DirectoryToDelete").Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
```

Comment: Nice, it worked, and how can I do it now with directories?

Answer (score 0):

You have to 'apply' the attributes by using:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, attributes);
```

Comment: So            FileAttributes attributes = FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

            var di = new DirectoryInfo(FileToDelete);
            di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
            File.SetAttributes(FileToDelete, attributes);